# How to connect with MySQL DB running as container in docker?

Tags: java, mysql, docker, jdbc

Can some give me any idea about how to connect with my mysql db which is running as a container in Docker on a virtual machine?

I have no idea about it, please help me.

What I am trying to do is :- I am writing a java program on my local machine and now I want to establish a jdbc connection with mysql. My MySQL DB is running as a docker container on a Virtual machine.

Does someone has any idea.

Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.15/**"what should I put here"**,"root","myrootpassword");

my ip address for the container is 172.17.0.2 and my guest ip is 10.0.2.15. My sql is running on port 3306.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Connecting to MySQL in a docker container works the same as connecting to a MySQL not running in a docker container.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your docker container should be able to bind its mysql port to any port on the VM. You do it with the `-p VMPort:containerPort` option of `docker run`.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#expose-incoming-ports

So this command

```
docker run -p 3306:3306 your-sql-container
```

Will publish the 3306 port of your container to the 3306 port of your VM.

At that point you should be able to hit your SQL with

```
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://10.0.2.15:3306/databaseName","root","myrootpassword");
```

I used your VM address and the binded port on the VM. You should replace `databaseName` with the actual name of your DB.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to put Database name there. 
`conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/dbname","username", "password");`
Check out [this link](https://www.mkyong.com/jdbc/how-to-connect-to-mysql-with-jdbc-driver-java/)

Also, it would not hurt to add port in your connector.