# Communications link failure , Spring Boot + MySql +Docker + Hibernate

Tags: mysql, spring, spring-boot, docker, docker-compose

I'm working with spring boot, hibernate & MySql. While running the application it is running well as per expectation . But while making the docker-compose file and running the app docker image with mysql docker image it gives this error.

> **Error**
> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
> java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused.

```
private Connection createConnection() throws SQLException 
{
        DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.jdbc.Driver());
        String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
        Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection(mysqlUrl, "root", "root");
        return connection;
}
```

> **Application.properties**

> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
> spring.datasource.username=root

> spring.datasource.password=root

Please guide me how to tackle this.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3'

services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
       - 8091:8091
    depends_on:
       - docker-mysql
```

Comment: I guess that since the service is running inside a docker image localhost is actually that docker image. You probably have another docker images where the database is  or not?

Comment: you might have a look at this question
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44780571/how-to-connect-with-mysql-db-running-as-container-in-docker

Comment: Here are a few reasons explained. you should check these out.
https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/02/java-net-ConnectException-Connection-refused.html

Comment: @JAMSHAID the first link share by you did't works for me sir.

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram right.

Comment: did you tried changing the path in your connection?

Comment: Yeah . I have tried to do so.But failed

Comment: change this ```jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false``` to ```jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false``` where docker-mysql is the name of the db service and docker embedded DNS will do the job of resolving service name to docker ip.

Comment: @Barath in application.properties or in createConnection() ?

Comment: However you want. you can also pass it as an env variable ```SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false```

Comment: @Barath will that work? is docker image running on docker-mysql?

Comment: Absolutely!! it should work

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram try on both the places

Comment: right. I never dealt with that in docker but Swing and online applications. So was curious about the docker path

Comment: @Barath it works for me . Thank you for your suggestion. But i am confused about one thing that  isn't possible that my spring app & image both works with the same code?

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram there might be a possibility for that but it might take more time while running the application. put the connection variable in condition if it is null after attempting to connect with localhost, it should try out the docker connection. if it is not null, it'll simply ignore the docker part. The condition will increase the running time here.

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram it may work in your machine where app & db runs on the same host ie localhost. But when you deploy as docker containers it defaults to bridge network. Technically you can achieve it using host network. There are tons of online materials may help you with better explanation. please read here [spring boot + mysql](https://www.javainuse.com/devOps/docker/docker-mysql)

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Issue is due to reference of localhost in the jdbc url.

Below configuration should work.

```
**docker-compose.yml**

version: '3'

services:
  docker-mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=database
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=root
    ports:
      - 3307:3306

  app:
    image: app:latest
    ports:
       - 8091:8091
    environment:
      SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL: jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    depends_on:
       - docker-mysql
```

Comment: it works for me. But my question is that do we need to add the same URL in application.prop while building the docker image?

Comment: Not needed  as it can be passed as an env variable to override the property

Comment: i want to run the application and docker image from the same code. How I am supposed to do so.As if we change the URL we are unable to run app.

Comment: @RaoWaqasAkram if thats the case use ```network_mode: "host"```. reference here [docker compose networking](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#network_mode)

Comment: I'm also facing the same issue. It is working fine which build the image form ( Window Docker Desktop ). It's giving error while building the image on Linux Docker with same code base and Docker file. I'm worried.

Comment: @SivaKaruppiah It would be great if you could share some logs.

Comment: The issue has been identified. The issue was the connection string usessl=false parameter. working as expected once added this.

Answer (score 7):

[This Docker forum discussion](https://forums.docker.com/t/cannot-connect-to-mysql-from-other-container/66836/5) helped me when I was running into this error. For me it was a problem with cache and I didn't get the error after running `docker-compose down --rmi all`

Comment: You save my day ! Thks

Answer (score 2):

For me, it was the version of `mysql`

`image: mysql:8` -> `image: mysql:5.7`

Comment: I follow many roads.  I don´t know but since I changed the version this works.

Answer (score 0):

did you tell your docker that it depends on SQL?
I mean is there something like this:

```
depends_on: 
 - mysql_server
```

in your docker-compose.yml ?

 looks like a configuration issue.

Comment: please have a look to updated question. I have updated the question and add the docker-compose.yml

Answer (score 0):

In my case I have provided proper privilege for my user to get connected from docker host and the error war gone.

I have provided % as host for my user which will provide access to connect from any host. The default root user will only connects from localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Put something like this in the application.properties

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://${MYSQL_HOST:localhost}:${MYSQL_PORT:3306}/test
spring.datasource.username=${MYSQL_USER:root}
spring.datasource.password=${MYSQL_PASSWORD:password}
```

Answer (score 0):

**With error of author question**

```
String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://localhost/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";

change localhost to name of container:  docker-mysql

String mysqlUrl = "jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false";
```

**I don't have error above but I have error Communications link failure because I configure SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL failure**

```
-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME:root' \
-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD:Raisingthebar123!!/ \
-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL:'jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/database? \autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false'
```

**Cause by:** SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME, SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME is right
but SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL fail because it have special & character

So I make a change NOT use : ALTERNATE use =

```
-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME='root' `

-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD='Raisingthebar123!!/' `

-e SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL='jdbc:mysql://docker-mysql:3306/database?autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false'
```