# Mysql database not accesible from Micronaut docker container

Tags: mysql, docker, micronaut

I'm trying to create docker containers on mi local enviroment. We have a Micronaut (Java) application and a MySQL database.

I created a container for my database with:

```
docker run -p 3307:3306 --name mysql-example -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql
```

When I connect from my app in and embbebed server outside of docker we can connect without problems. Mi application.yml have the next configuration:

```
datasources:
  default:
    url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307/example?allowPublicKeyRetrieval=true&generateSimpleParameterMetadata=true&zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&verifyServerCertificate=false&useSSL=false
    driverClassName: com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
    username: root
    password: password
    schema-generate: CREATE_DROP
    dialect: MYSQL
```

Then I tried to create the Micronaut app image and run it on a container. My Dockerfile contains:

```
FROM maven:3.6.1-jdk-8
COPY target/example-0.1.jar example.jar
EXPOSE 8080
CMD java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Xmx128m -jar example.jar
```

I first generate JAR:

```
mvnw package
```

And then I generate docker image:

```
docker build -t example .
```

And when I test my app deployed in a container I have the next exception:

```
Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Could you help me with this issue? Thanks :-)

Comment: Questions like [Communications link failure , Spring Boot + MySql +Docker + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880998/communications-link-failure-spring-boot-mysql-docker-hibernate) discuss this, but they are almost all focused on a Docker Compose setup, which provides some of the required networking setup for you.  Also see the newer answers to [How to communicate between Docker containers via "hostname"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30545023/how-to-communicate-between-docker-containers-via-hostname).

Answer (score 1):

Since you run your MySQL container with `--name mysql-example` then you should connect it as

```
jdbc:mysql://mysql-example:3307
```

not

```
jdbc:mysql://localhost:3307
```

Comment: You need to use the standard MySQL port 3306 (connections between containers ignore `docker run -p` port mappings), and both containers need to be on the same `docker run --net` network.

Comment: I tried to create containers using:
`docker run --network=host --name mysql-example -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password -d mysql`
`docker run --network=host --name example-container example`
But I received: `java.net.UnknownHostException: mysql-example: Name or service not known`