# Spring Boot and PostgreSQL with Docker

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, docker

I have a Spring Boot 3 + PostgreSQL application, I'm currently using Postgresql with Docker

```
# Define a imagem base a ser utilizada
FROM openjdk:17-jdk-slim

# Define o diretório de trabalho da aplicação
WORKDIR /app

# Copia os arquivos de build para o container
COPY target/viaAvaliation-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar /app/via.jar

# Expõe a porta utilizada pela aplicação
EXPOSE 8080

# Define o comando a ser executado quando o container iniciar
CMD ["java", "-jar", "via.jar"]
```

However, if I add the Dockerfile

```
services:
  postgres:
    image: 'postgres:14.2'
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    restart: always
    deploy:
      mode: replicated
      replicas: 1
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=root
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin
```

And I add the Spring application in dockercompose, I have the error of
o`rg.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Connection to localhost:5432 refused. Check that the hostname and port are correct and that the postmaster is accepting TCP/IP connections`
I've already added the url to the application.yml by changing localhost to the dockercompose service-name and nothing works!

Comment: How are you configuring `spring.datasource.url`?  (Consider adding a `SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL` environment variable for a Compose-specific setup.)  Also see [Communications link failure , Spring Boot + MySql +Docker + Hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58880998/communications-link-failure-spring-boot-mysql-docker-hibernate) which discusses a similar class of problem.

Comment: I add spring.datasource.url! but, not working